# Get value from a array

Tags: php, arrays

### update

how can I retrieve this value? I need to do that if I will write the value to my database.

```
array(3) {
 [1]=> NULL  

 [2]=> array(2) {

    [123]=>

    int(123)

    [122]=>

    int(0)

  }

 [3]=> NULL

}
```

Comment: That doesn't even make any sense. Please paste your output properly.

Comment: Please provide some more information. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I think you missed a closing bracket. Besides this, where to this line goes? Who captures this result? Shouldn't it be assigned to an `lvalue`? EDIT: see @Felix Kling

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://ie2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php. It has loads of other information as well if you're new to PHP. Also since you want to insert it into a mysql database be sure to look as is_numeric and mysql_real_escape_string to help protect you against SQL injection.

Comment: PHP has a very fine manual. Please read it.

Comment: @yannick Which value is it? You can get the `123` via `$myArray[2][123]` if that's any help.

Comment: You seem to have edited you question, but didn't make it any clearer. Pelase be more verbose.

Answer (score 8):

There is something missing in your output. I assume it looks something like:

```
// var_dump($array);
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "39"
}
```

so you can access the value with `$array[0]`. Simple array access.

As arrays are the most important data structure in PHP, you should learn how to deal with them.
Read [**PHP: Arrays**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

**Update:**

Regarding your update, which value do you want? You have a multidimensional array. This is what you will get:

```
$array[1] // gives null
$array[2] // gives an array
$array[2][123] // gives the integer 123
$array[2][122] // gives the integer 0
$array[3] // gives null
```

Maybe you also want (have) to loop over the inner array to get all values:

```
foreach($array[2] as $key => $value) {
    // do something with $key and $value
}
```

As I said, **read the documentation,** it contains everything you need to know. Accessing arrays in PHP is not much different than in other programming languages.

The PHP manual contains a lot of examples, it is a pretty could documentation. Use it!

Comment: @fljx: Not sure what you want to say. My remark is only that he didn't paste the complete output of `var_dump`. I'm  not creating an array if this is what you think.

Comment: All right. We agree in that. What I said is that it should work by explicitly stating the array index or not. `array(1){[0]=>string(2)"39"}` or `array(1){string(2)"39"}` will both work.

Answer (score 1):

If your array is referenced as `$myArray`, you can get the string `39` via `$myArray[0]`, i.e., this zeroth item.